# One of my graphics cards no longer displays in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I have a computer with two NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 graphics cards installed (let's call those G1 and G2). I have three monitors - two plugged into one card, one plugged into the other.

This setup has worked well for years, but when I turned my computer on this morning one of the three monitors is "off" and "showing black." (I am using Windows 7.)

I tried changing around what monitors were attached to what graphics cards and found that it was one particular graphics card - G1 - that was causing the whatever monitors were plugged into it to "show black." That is, if monitors M1 and M2 were plugged into G1 and monitor M3 was plugged into G2 then M3 would display and M1 and M2 were black. If just M2 was plugged into G1 and M1 and M3 were plugged into G2 then M1 and M3 would work fine but M2 would be black.

My next thought was to try disabling the faulty graphics card, G1 (it's located on PCI bus 1, per Device Manager). So I went to Device Manager, right-clicked on the G1 and disabled it. I then rebooted.

On reboot, whatever monitor(s) are plugged into G1 turns *on* while the other(s) show black! This is the reverse of what was happening when both graphics cards were enabled. Moreover, the resolution is in the Safe Mode style (like 640x480), so I presume what's happening is that Windows is seeing that there is no driver installed for the primary graphics card and therefore is defaulting to the VGA drive for it, and (for whatever reason) ignoring the second graphics card.

If I then re-enable the graphics card G1 and reboot, I'm back to my initial situation - those monitors plugged into G2 work fine, those plugged into G1 "show black."

I'm unclear what exactly is going on here. Clearly all three monitors are working, since I can get them to work by plugging them into G2. Clearly video can be delivered via G1 because if I uninstall the graphics card Windows, those monitor(s) plugged into G1 display (albeit in VGA mode). But once the graphics card tries to use the driver, it sends no video feed to the plugged in monitor(s).

What's weird, is that if I plug in a monitor into G1, which again is on PCI bus 1, and then I reboot, the BIOS startup screen comes on that monitor and the Windows loading logo comes up on that, but once Windows starts, it goes black. So clearly some sort of display message is getting out to that monitor.

Is the graphics card just fried or something? I figure my next approach would be to buy a new card and plug that in and see if I can't get that working, but I was hoping someone would have another idea or thing to try before having to trek out to the store and take apart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about these types of symptoms online, I presumed that the graphics card had a problem with higher resolution modes.

I ended up buying another GeForce GT 730 and replacing the non-functioning one with it and now I'm back to three working displays. So that was the problem.